# Regular Expression - Finding 4 digits in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with finding a simple regular expression to search through a string and find and pull out 4 digits with no whitespace between.

For example, I am trying to find a year in a string such as 1965. If the string said **"30 Jan 1965"** and I wanted to pull out **"1965"**, how would I go about it?

I have found others on the internet but I just get an empty set returned. Thank you

Comment: Are they always going to be dates? If so, it'd be better to convert to a `DateTime` object and then use the `.Year` property of the object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The regex `\b\d{4}\b` will do the trick.

Comment: visual studio says it doesnt recognise the \d escape sequence

Comment: @user1290653 Add the character '@' infront of the string or use double backslashes

Comment: THANK YOU works perfectly. and @MarickOWA i feel foolish, forgot about that haha

Answer (score 3):

An example. Just add it to a main method.

```
string pattern = @"\d{4}";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
Console.WriteLine(r.Match("30 Jan 1965"));
Console.WriteLine(r.Matches("30 Jan 1965 2001 2010 test ").Count);
// will output 
// 1965
// 3
```

Comment: I used Match BirthYear = Regex.Match(kvpInd.Value.birth.date, @"(?<BrtYr>\b\d{4}\b)");
and
BirthYear.Groups["BrtYr"].ToString()